# What's the first argument of namedtuple used for?

Tags: python, namedtuple, python-collections

We use `namedtuple` like this:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
>>> p=Point(1,2)
>>> p.x
1
```

I found the first argument of `namedtuple` seems useless, since:

Firstly, we can not use it (to create an instance, for example):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> P = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
>>> p = Point(1,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Point' is not defined
```

Secondly, there seems no constraint for it (for example, we don't have to make it unique):

```
>>> P1 = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
>>> P2 = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y', 'z'])
>>> p1 = P1(1,2)
>>> p2 = P2(1,2,3)
>>> p1
Point(x=1, y=2)
>>> p2
Point(x=1, y=2, z=3)
```

I did not find a explanation from the [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or by googling. There is a relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432203/namedtuple-applications-of-different-type-names-in-the-same-definition), but it did not answer why `namedtuple` need the first argument and how it can be used or when it's necessary.

Comment: Think about it - if the class *didn't* have a `__name__`, what would the `repr` look like? If you set `ClassName = namedtuple('ClassName', ...)` then you can use e.g. `eval` to recreate a given instance.

Comment: Where do you think the name part from namedtuple was coming from?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I had a misunderstanding about class names before, I thought them should be unique.

Comment: @WKPlus they generally *should* be, yes, but aren't *required* to be.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It sets the name of the generated class:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
>>> Point
<class '__main__.Point'>
>>> Point = namedtuple('Foobar', ['x', 'y'])
>>> Point
<class '__main__.Foobar'>
```

The `Point` name in your globals is just a reference to the generated class, the class *itself* needs to have a name. The name cannot be taken from the variable to which the object is assigned, because the class is generated *first* and only *then* assigned in a separate step (after the `namedtuple()` call returns).

It doesn't need to be unique in the same way that a class name doesn't need to be unique when using `class`:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> Bar = Foo
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> Bar
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> Foo
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

You usually avoid that kind of thing by keeping names unique per module, but you don't *have* to.

The name is there for debugging purposes; in tracebacks and in `repr()` output the name is shown to help you figure out what class is used.

To Python, it *doesn't matter* if the generated class reuses a name. It does to the `pickle` module; if you need to be able to pickle your named tuple class instances, make sure you pick a name that matches the global by which `pickle` can later load it again. But if re-using a name makes sense to you or doesn't actively hinder your code development or debugging tasks, then by all means, reuse the name or pick anything you like.

Comment: But when I define two named tuple with the same name, it works fine, why?

Comment: @WKPlus why *wouldn't* it?

Comment: @WKPlus: I can create multiple classes with the same name too. Or functions. For debugging purposes and clarity you want to keep them unique, but it is not enforced.

Comment: Two named tuples with the same name but contain different attributes, it still can work, does this make sense?

Comment: @WKPlus: if to you as a developer it doesn't make sense, then don't use duplicate names. But in some circumstances it is easy enough to generate named tuple classes on demand and the name *doesn't matter*, so generating new unique names for each doesn't make sense either.

Comment: @WKPlus: but usually *nothing breaks* when you reuse a name. If you want to pickle instances of the named tuple class, you need to have a name that matches the global by which you store it (so unpickling can find the class again), but on the whole, Python **doesn't care**.

Comment: "The name is there for debugging purposes;To Python, it doesn't matter if the generated class reuses a name", this enhances my understanding:)